# Should I lube the gaskets of my kegs?

Tags: kegging, keg, corny-keg, packaging

I am new to kegging my beer. In a video I saw somebody putting Vaseline on all of the gaskets of his corny-kegs. I was wondering if this kills the foam of the beer. Or do I have to lube the gaskets for a better seal?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vaseline is petroleum based and will degrade black orings.

Use food grade silicone spray to keep your keg seals fresh and lubricated.